# How to calculate and reshape more than 1 bn items of data into PySpark?

Tags: pandas, numpy, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

Our use case is to read data from BQ and caculate by using pandas and numpy.reshape to turn it into input for the model, sample code like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Source Data
feature = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
    .option('table', TABLE_NAME) \
    .load()

test = feature.to_pandas_on_spark().sort_values(by = ['col1','col2'], ascending = True).drop(['col1','col3','col5'], axis = 1)

test = (test - test.mean())/(test.std())

row = int(len(test)/100)
row2 = 50
col3 = 100

feature_array = np.reshape(feature_nor.values, (row,row2,col3))
```

`feature.to_pandas_on_spark()` will collect all data into driver memory and for small amout of data it can work, but for more than 15 Billion data it can not handle this.

I try to convert `to_pandas_on_spark()` to spark dataframe so that it can compute in parallell:

```
sorted_df = feature.sort('sndr_id').sort('date_index').drop('sndr_id').drop('date_index').drop('cal_dt')
mean_df = sorted_df.select(*[f.mean(c).alias(c) for c in sorted_df.columns])
std_df = sorted_df.select(*[f.stddev(c).alias(c) for c in sorted_df.columns])
```

Since the function is different from the pandas api, so I cannot verify these code and for the last reshape operation(`np.reshape(feature_nor.values, (row,row2,col3))`) dataframe doesn't support this function, is there a good solution to replace it?

I want to know how to handle 1B data in a efficient way and without memory overflow, including how to use numpy's reshape and pandas's computation operations, any answers will be super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise not to use pandas or numpy on a dataset of this size, there usually is some Spark function to solve your problem, even firing up a UDF or using pandas on spark comes with a significant performance loss.
What exactly are your reshape criteria?
Maybe [pivot](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-pivot-and-unpivot-dataframe/) helps?

Comment: Hi @cgi_dus, I will reshape the data into a 3D array with 100 columns and 50 rows for each instance, similar to [[[50*100]] * 250M], how can I use pivot for this case? I see I've 100 columns.

Comment: Do you have anything you could group on?
Then you could also try grouping and vectorization:
`df.groupBy("col1").agg(F.collect_list("col2")).show()`